# How to open a database with SQuirrel SQL Client? (Database not found)

Tags: java, derby, squirrel-sql

I've recently been fiddling around with databases and finally. So, naturally, I turned to SQuirrel to open and view my work, but it seems I can't get the formatting for the alias right.
Currently what I have been trying is:

`jdbc:derby:C:\path_to_my\database`

Is this the correct format for `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver`? I can't find anything particularly useful online, unfortunately. 
Thanks, 
Michael

Comment: Fyi, this is the error that I get: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

PDFManager: Database 'C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\Computer Science\Java projects\PDFManager' not found.
class org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedSQLException: Database 'C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\Computer Science\Java projects\PDFManager' not found.

Comment: You're passing the project directory. You're supposed to pass the [database name](https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html). Did you not find the Derby documentation, or was it not "particularly useful"?

Comment: What am I supposed to do? Give the file path to the database? Or do I simply put jdbc:derby:name-of-the-database? The derby documentation didn't really answer my question, haha.

Comment: The name of the database. Exactly like the documentation shows. If you run the example code, it works. Therefore it has a working connection string. That connection string has the name of the database. Do you have an existing database? If so, then you already know the name, as you've already connected to it with a connection string somewhere. If not, then you get to create a database and choose the name.

Comment: Well, when I simply put jdbc:derby:PDFManager, it doesn't find anything. It only works if I copy the database inside the SQuirrel Folder. I'm on a school computer, so everything is kinda messed up, so I think that's probably why stuff is acting up. Thank you for your concern though, Michael.

Comment: Possibly the embedded space in `Computer Science` is causing a problem?